# OpenGL GLDeleteTextures() fails to delete the first texture

Tags: c, opengl

I set up a number of textures at the beginning of my code (C). Each texture is generated correctly (without errors) and I store the texture name as a GLuint in an image structure for later use.
At the end of the program, the GLuint's are passed back to GLdeleteTextures() and the program exits.

The problem is I keep getting an error at the first attempt to use GLDeleteTextures(). All subsequent calls to GLDeleteTextures() do not produce the error.

The error (from gluErrorString) states 'invalid enumerant'.

Extra Info.
All textures are unbound before deletion with a call to glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, NULL).
All texture names (GLuints) are verified at creation and they are the same names used when deleting.
The order of the textures when deleting is irrelevant, it's the first call to delete that's the problem.

Current workaround.
I've found that repeating glDeleteTextures() on the first texture works, eg...

```
glDeleteTextures(1,&MyImage->texName);   // Will produce 'invalid enumerant'

glDeleteTextures(1,&MyImage->texName);   // This time it will work!
```

I've double checked the code above by generating new textures after the second deletion and comparing the texture names. The texture is indeed deleted after the second call and placed back into the system correctly.

I have the Red Book and it's a little vague on texture deletion. Are there a set of explicit steps that must be peformed to delete textures correctly?

Comment: Are you sure that that line is generating the error? It seems likely that the error is pending from a previous call before the glDeleteTextures. Move the error check line before the first deleteTextures.

Comment: Post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: I just came to the same conclusion. It's not glDeleteTextures. It's seems it's coming from glEnable(GL_ALPHA). Spooky. Thankyou genpfault.

Comment: @OP: If this question has been answered, please convert my answer to community wiki else delete it.

Answer (score 0):

The fault was not with `glDeleteTextures()` rather was coming from `glEnable(GL_ALPHA)`.